# Docker image retag for build promotion

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-docker

I am trying to promote a docker image in my Jenkins pipeline using Jenkins docker plugin but I am able to do so as I am getting following error.

```
"docker tag" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker tag --help'.

Usage:  docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE
```

I can see the following in the logs

```
docker tag artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:latest artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:latest artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/test:latest
```

Pipeline code:

```
testImage = docker.image("artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:latest")

testImage.pull()

testImage.push("artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:latest artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/test:latest" )
```

Any idea what's wrong here...

Edit#1:
If I do following the I get different error.

```
testImage = docker.image("artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:latest")

testImage.pull()

testImage.tag("artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/test:latest")

testImage.push( )
```

Error:

```
Error parsing reference: "artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appnamee/dev:artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/test:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are running into some confusion on what each docker command does and how to add new tags to an existing docker on your workspace.

On Jenkins world, [docker commands behave like this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)

`docker.image` takes a single argument, composing `IMAGE_NAME`:`TAG`

`docker.tag` with a single argument, will assume `TAG` (this command will not change 'IMAGE_NAME', it will only change the `TAG` part)

`docker.push` takes a single optional argument, `TAG`, meant to push an already existing Image with a different tag only (not with a different `IMAGE_NAME`)

On your pipeline, you are trying to change the `IMAGE_NAME` part of the docker identifier, since, none of the above commands help you.

**NEW SOLUTION**

Another way of approaching this issue is to make the `IMAGE_NAME` change via shell, and then use the Jenkins plugins to map and push the images

```
sh("docker tag ORIGINAL_IMAGE_NAME:ORIGINAL_TAG NEW_IMAGE_NAME:NEW_TAG")
newImage = docker.image("NEW_IMAGE_NAME:NEW_TAG")
# docker plugin should find the image on the localhost, so there is no need to pull it form the registry
newImage.push
```

on your code, something like

```
sh ('docker tag artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:latest artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/test:latest')
testImage2 = docker.image('artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/test:latest')
```

and then, push each image independently from the other

```
testImage.push()
testImage2.push()
```

**DID NOT WORK**

You could try supplying 2 arguments to `docker.tag`, such as

```
docker.tag (ORIGINAL_IMAGE_NAME:ORIGINAL_TAG, NEW_IMAGE_NAME:NEW_TAG)
```

in your case, something like

```
testImage.tag ("artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/dev:latest" "artifactory.mycompany.com/docker-dev/appname/test:latest")
```

and then, push each image independently from the other

```
testImage.push (ORIGINAL_IMAGE_NAME:ORIGINAL_TAG)
testImage.push (NEW_IMAGE_NAME:NEW_TAG)
```

Comment: Thanks matus, testImage.tag("ORIG_IMG:latest" "NEW_IMG:latest") produces error unexpected token: ...:latest" "... and if I do testImage.tag("ORIG_IMG:latest "  + " NEW_IMG:latest") then I get error "docker tag" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker tag --help'.

Usage:  docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE.   In the logs I see the same 1st error as in question

Comment: I think the docker plugin tag option is considering the supplied value as a tag to the existing image name and not considering it as a full image name with tag. This behavior seems to be different from how docker tag works... U can try it to replicate the behavior

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta, I updated the answer with an alternative solution that I believe it might work better